# How do I get hour and minutes from NSDate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, hour

In my application I need to get the hour and minute separately:

```
NSString *currentHour=[string1 substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0,2)];
        int currentHourInNumber=[currentHour intValue];
```

Consider `string1` contains `11:59:13 AM` which is coming from datepicker.

Here if I use above code, it's okay to get hour if it's greater than 9. Else I need to change `NSMakeRange(0,1)` to get hour between 1 to 9.

Are there any methods to get the hour, minutes, etc?

Please provide me sample code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the hour of the day with Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137692/how-to-get-the-hour-of-the-day-with-swift)

Answer (score 266, accepted):

Use an [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to convert `string1` into an `NSDate`, then get the required [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

**Obj-C**:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"<your date format goes here"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string1];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:date];
NSInteger hour = [components hour];
NSInteger minute = [components minute];
```

**Swift 1 and 2**:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "Your date Format"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(string1)
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let comp = calendar.components([.Hour, .Minute], fromDate: date)
let hour = comp.hour
let minute = comp.minute
```

**Swift 3**:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "Your date Format"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string1)
let calendar = Calendar.current
let comp = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)
let hour = comp.hour
let minute = comp.minute
```

More about the [dateformat](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) is on the official unicode site

Comment: Hi One more doubt, is it possible to change the hour, minute in NSDate

Comment: To change the hour and minute, maybe look into NSDate's + dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:. That method lets you add a specific amount of seconds to date (and return a new date).

Comment: On iOS, "components" is only available since version 8.0. How about < 8.0?

Comment: @Rhuantavan https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/components:fromDate: "Available in iOS 2.0 and later."
I have definitely use this API for years.

Comment: I guess it is a bug in XCode since it was reporting this to be 8.0. I should have checked the sources or online docs. My bad.

Answer (score 53):

If you only need it for presenting as a string the following code is much easier

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

NSString *startTimeString = [formatter stringFromDate:startTimePicker.date];
```

Answer (score 45):

This seems to me to be what the question is after, no need for formatters:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:date];
NSInteger hour = [components hour];
NSInteger minute = [components minute];
```

Comment: How to get AM or PM ?

Answer (score 6):

`NSDateComponents`

All you need can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html

Answer (score 4):

If you were to use the C library then this could be done:

```
time_t t;
struct tm * timeinfo;

time (&t);
timeinfo = localtime (&t);

NSLog(@"Hour: %d Minutes: %d", timeinfo->tm_hour, timeinfo->tm_min);
```

And using Swift:

```
var t = time_t()
time(&t)
let x = localtime(&t)

println("Hour: \(x.memory.tm_hour) Minutes: \(x.memory.tm_min)")
```

For further guidance see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/

Answer (score 4):

With iOS 8, Apple introduced a helper method to retrieve the `hour`, `minute`, `second` and `nanosecond` from an NSDate object.

Objective-C

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate currentDate];
NSInteger hour = 0;
NSInteger minute = 0;
NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[currentCalendar getHour:&hour minute:&minute second:NULL nanosecond:NULL fromDate:date];
NSLog(@"the hour is %ld and minute is %ld", (long)hour, (long)minute);
```

Swift

```
let date = NSDate()
var hour = 0
var minute = 0
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
    calendar.getHour(&hour, minute: &minute, second: nil, nanosecond: nil, fromDate: date)
    print("the hour is \(hour) and minute is \(minute)")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 2.0**

You can do following thing to get hours and minute from a date :

```
let dateFromat = NSDateFormatter()
dateFromat.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
let date = dateFromat.dateFromString(string1) // In your case its string1
print(date) // you will get - 11:59 AM
```

Comment: Use [NSDateFormatter](http://www.codingexplorer.com/swiftly-getting-human-readable-date-nsdateformatter/) for brief details.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2.0

```
    let dateNow = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let hour = calendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Hour, fromDate: dateNow)
    let minute = calendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Minute, fromDate: dateNow)
    print(String(hour))
    print(String(minute))
```

Please do take note of the cast to String in the print statement, you can easily assign that value to variables, like this:

```
var hoursString = String(hour)
var minutesString = String(minute)
```

Then you can concatenate values  like this:

```
var compoundString = "\(hour):\(minute)"
print(compoundString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension on NSDate

```
    @interface NSDate (KTelDateUtility)

-(NSUInteger)dateYear;
-(NSUInteger)dateMonth;
-(NSUInteger)dateDay;

-(NSUInteger)dateHours;
-(NSUInteger)dateMins;
-(NSUInteger)dateSeconds;

@end

    @implementation NSDate (KTelDateUtility)

-(NSDateComponents*)dateCalenderComponents {
    NSDateComponents* dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:self];
    return dateComponents;
}

-(NSDateComponents*)dateTimeComponents {
    NSDateComponents* timeComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:self];
    return timeComponents;
}

-(NSUInteger)dateYear {
    return [[self dateCalenderComponents] year];
}

-(NSUInteger)dateMonth {
    return [[self dateCalenderComponents] month];
}

-(NSUInteger)dateDay {
    return [[self dateCalenderComponents] day];
}

-(NSUInteger)dateHours {
    return [[self dateTimeComponents] hour];
}

-(NSUInteger)dateMins {
    return [[self dateTimeComponents] minute];
}

-(NSUInteger)dateSeconds {
    return [[self dateTimeComponents] second];
}


@end
```