# How to get the hour of the day with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

How would I get the hour of the day in Swift.
I have tried `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`, but I'm afraid I'm just starting with Swift.

Answer (score 199):

**Swift 5.0 / 4.0 / 3.0**

```
let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())
```

Or, if you're interested in `12 hour AM/PM` date format, then use [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter)

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "hh a" // "a" prints "pm" or "am"
let hourString = formatter.string(from: Date()) // "12 AM"
```

If you want minutes, seconds and others, do as following

```
let date = Date() // save date, so all components use the same date
let calendar = Calendar.current // or e.g. Calendar(identifier: .persian)

let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
let minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
let second = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
```

Check out available components on [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar.component):

```
.era, .year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second,
.weekday, .weekdayOrdinal, .quarter, weekOfMonth, .weekOfYear,
.yearForWeekOfYear, .nanosecond, .calendar, .timezone
```

**Swift 2.0**

```
let hour = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Hour, fromDate: NSDate())
```

**Swift 1.0**

```
let hour = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.CalendarUnitHour, fromDate: NSDate())
```

Comment: With Swift 2: `let hour = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Hour, fromDate: NSDate())`

Comment: it's nice to see how Swift improves over time. Swift 3.0 version is way more readable that Swift 1.0 one

Comment: You want to use "h a" not "hh a" If you want 7 pm not 07 pm

Comment: How can I get all the hours in a day ? for example something like:
let hoursArray = formatter.string(from: Date()) // 12 AM, 1 AM ... etc .. until all 24 hrs are there.

Comment: The solution involving `DateFormatter` doesn't doesn't seem to be working in Swift 5.6.   The line `formatter.dateFormat = "hh a"` throws a bunch of errors.

Answer (score 30):

**Swift 3:**

```
let date = Date()// Aug 25, 2017, 11:55 AM
let calendar = Calendar.current

let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date) //11
let minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: date) //55
let sec = calendar.component(.second, from: date) //33
let weekDay = calendar.component(.weekday, from: date) //6 (Friday)
```

Get any of component available from the API below

```
public enum Component {
    case era
    case year
    case month
    case day
    case hour
    case minute
    case second
    case weekday
    case weekdayOrdinal
    case quarter
    case weekOfMonth
    case weekOfYear
    case yearForWeekOfYear
    case nanosecond
    case calendar
    case timeZone
}
```

**Swift 2:**

```
let currentHour = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Hour, fromDate: NSDate())
```

---

This could be enough :

```
let currentDate = NSDate() // You can input the custom as well 
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate:  currentDate)
let currentHour = components.hour // You can play around with the ""components""
```

Comment: Thankyou, but IMHO this code is to complex because I just want to get the hour of the day

Comment: Sorry , didn't get you. what do you mean **I just want to get the hour of the day**? and also **code is to complex**?

Comment: @KumarKL how to get day in full i.e Friday, saturday etc ?

Comment: The latest version of swift is just let calendar = Calendar.current

Comment: Isn't it `Calendar.current` instead of `Calendar.current()` in `Swift 3`?

Answer (score 7):

If you want the current hour in a String, this is as short and readable I could think of.

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "HH"

let timeString = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
```

Comment: I understand your code but after all, I would need an integer instead of a string, but thank you very much for your help, I believe that this code can be very useful

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to find the easiest solution after struggling for a time

```
let dateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.HourCalendarUnit, fromDate: NSDate())
let nHourOfDay = dateComponents.hour
```

Comment: could you even remove "NSCalendarUnit"? I'm away from my Mac and can't test it.

Comment: @JeanLeMoignan Yes, you can. I tested it.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 2.0:

```
let hour = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(NSCalendarUnit.Hour, fromDate: NSDate())
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reference example for how I do it ([DateUtils.swift](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhh1o9uc12uqmav/DateUtils.swift?dl=0)) -

**Example Use:**

```
    let today = DateUtils.getToday();
    let hr  = DateUtils.getHours(today);
    let min = DateUtils.getMinutes(today);
    ... (etc.) ...
```

**DateUtils.swift:**

```
//Field wrapper routines
class func getToday() -> Date               { return Date(); }
class func getHours(_ date : Date) -> Int   { return Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: date); }
class func getMinutes(_ date : Date) -> Int { return Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: date); }
... (continued for all fields, see file) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the integer value of the current hour in one step like this:

```
let currentHour = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.Hour, fromDate: NSDate()).hour
```